# Why won't vim source my ftplugin_after.vim file?

Tags: autocmd, set, ftplugin, init

I have a file called `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin_after.vim`, which contains `set incsearch ignorecase smartcase number relativenumber autoindent shiftwidth=8 tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 expandtab showbreak=¶ notimeout`. I am mainly concerned about the tabstop.

I used to set tab settings in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, until I noticed it was being overridden in some files. The culprit was `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/`. I managed to get vim to ignore them, but I missed some of the features.

I even tried setting these values using `autocmd VimEnter`, but that didn't work. I expect the `after/` directory is the best method.

I just want my tab settings to be applied to all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a file called `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin_after.vim`

The correct path you're looking for is actually:

```
~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/filetype.vim
```

Note that `ftplugin` needs to be a *directory*, and that the `*.vim` file inside it must be named after the filetype of the files you would like to match.

The `ftplugin` scripts must *always* match a specific filetype, you can't really create a script in that directory to apply to all files you edit, regardless of filetype...

> The culprit was `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/`

Yes, but *which* script inside `ftplugin/`? The scripts on that directory will only be loaded based on the filetype of the buffer you're currently editing.

You can use the command `:set ft?` to find which filetype is set to the current buffer, so you can use it in your `ftplugin/` override.

> which contains `set incsearch ignorecase smartcase number relativenumber autoindent shiftwidth=8 tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 expandtab showbreak=¶ notimeout`. I am mainly concerned about the tabstop.

Note that you should typically use `setlocal` instead of `set` in an `ftplugin` script. Since it's loaded for each buffer, based on the filetype, you'll want to make sure you only define buffer-local settings and mappings, so that they only affect buffers of that specific filetype and not others.

(One final subtlety of `ftplugin` scripts is that you might want to define a [`b:undo_ftplugin`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#undo_ftplugin) variable, with commands that can be used to undo its actions. This is used if you ever change filetypes of a buffer, in which case Vim will be able to undo the changes from the previous filetype before applying the ones for the next filetype.)

Comment: This works, but I was hoping to get one file to override all ftplugins, rather than a file for each filetype.